# Understanding why you need convexity to show that f does not depend on the first variable

Tags: multivariable-calculus, convex-analysis, partial-derivative

[image]

My question is why do I need convexity here ?

Here is the solution that uses the convexity:
Let $a,b \in A$ such that $a = (a_{1},a_{2},..,a_{n}) \ , b = (b_{1},a_{2},...,a_{n})$ we need to show that $f(a) = f(b)$ define $g: [0,1] \to\Bbb R$ $g(t) = f(a_{1}+t(b_{1}+a_{1}),a_{2},...,a_{n})$ now we show that $g'(t) = 0$ so she is constant and we are done.. so I think here we use convexity to show that $g$ is well defined.

but why can't I solve that like this:

define $L = \{a \in \Bbb R | (a,a_{2},...,a_{n})\in A\}$ so lets define $g: L \to\Bbb R$ $g(a) = f(a,a_{2},...,a_{n})$ now $A$ is open so $L+h \in A$ for $h$ small enough so $g(a+h)$ is defined
lets find $g'(a)$

$$g'(a) = \lim_{h\to 0}\frac{g(a+h)-g(a)}{h}=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(a+h,a_{2},...,a_{n})-f(a,a_{2},...,a_{n})}{h} = \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_{1}}(a,a_{2},...a_{n})=0$$

so again $g$ is constant and we are done.

In the later solution I did not use convexity so the solution is not valid but I really can't put my hands where the mistake is..

And can you help me find an example for a function $f$ that satisfies the condition above but $A$ is just open and $f$ is not constant?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider two separate domains, for example
$$I_1=(-2,-1)\times(0,1)\;\;\;\;\;I_2=(0,1)\times(0,1)\\\Omega=I_1\cup I_2$$
and then consider the following function
$$ f(x,y) = \begin{cases}
0 & x\in (-2,-1)\\
1 & x\in (1,0)\\
\end{cases}$$
Your proof works for this kind of set and function since what you've proven is that for a given $x\in(-2,-1)\cup (0,1)$ it is constant in the connected component. You need convexity or connectedness to prove it is really constant (in the case it has two separate domains).

Answer (score 2):

Here is a counterexample that it is not enough to replace "convex" by "connected".
We consider a square with a slit:
$$
A = (-1,1)^2 \setminus ( \{0\} \times [0,1]).$$
We define $f \colon A \to \mathbb R$ via
$$
f(x,y) = \begin{cases}
\frac12y^2 & \text{if } x > 0, y > 0, \\
-\frac12y^2& \text{if } x < 0, y > 0, \\
0 & \text{if } y \le 0.
\end{cases}$$